# change question

Tags: support, specific-question

I have asked [How to connect multiple bluetooth A2DP/HFP-compatible phones to one bluetooth headset?](https://superuser.com/questions/698764/how-to-connect-more-than-2-phones-to-one-bluetooth-headset) hoping to find if "is there a product that does X"; however with strict "product recommendation rules" that got my other questions closed in the past I was afraid and asked "how to do X" instead, which might not get as much involvement into getting an answer by users.

I performed further research on meta.superuser.com and (correct me if I'm wrong) understand that generally "is there a product that does X" is tolerated while "what is the best product that does X" not.

So now if I retitle my question from "how to do X" to "is there a product that does X?" and rephrase the question describing the function of the imaginary product, will the change be accepted by editors? Will that break other rules that are found only when breaking them?

To complicate things a bit further, the question also has an open bounty and if kept in current form I should award one answer that is logically correct in relation with the question; however that answer is obvious (from the logical point of view) and does not help me to find the product!

Comment: Instead of asking for a pre-made product, start asking for a solution to your actual problem. Ensure to include what you've already tried, and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: You can always edit your own question.  Your own edits to your own question don't go through a review process.  Changing the title of the question of course won't make it a good question or a bad question or make it a good question or a bad question.  The current question seems good enough.